# Load a mutable list dynamically (fe. for recyclerview) from a backend. Probably used in Facebook, GMail, 9GAG, Instagram and co

Tags: rest, android-recyclerview, web, backend

I got a question for loading a extremely long mutable list of posts.

First of all, for people who don't know android's recyclerview: you load a batch of posts from a server, like 25 posts, and you show them in a scrollable list. when you scroll further, and you want to access the item on position 25, you load the next batch from the server. The recyclerview is my concrete problem, but the same problem would occur on websites and so on.

So this is the problem: Lets say the posts are ordered by likes and we have posts in the order {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h} with decreasing likes. Our batchsize size is 3, so we always load 3 posts. Our screen can show 2 posts at a time. We begin with loading {a, b, c}. We are waiting 10 minutes before we scroll down and load pos3, pos4 and pos5. In this time the likes are going different and the new order is {a, b, d, c, f, e, g, h}. Our next batch will be {c, f, e}, since our backend request will be sth like backend.com/get3items/?batch=1. Since our screen can show 2 posts, it could show pos2 and pos3, which is {c, c}.

Same could happen if we remove or add an item. batchsize=1, list={a, b, c}. We load a. A new item g is added to the beginning of the list. We load a again.

Other facts: The number of items on the screen can be higher or lower then the batchsize. The changes of the list can happen at any position. Maybe we are loading batch#500 but there was a change at pos0. The code behind backend.com/get3items/?batch=1 could be done with "select * from items order by likes desc limit 3, 3"

For the answer I thought of this approaches:

1) The server notifies the client that a change happened via observer pattern. not useful, because if there are like 1 million subscribers, the server dies on every change (+ it is not restful-friendly, since the server has to track subscribers).

2) The server can calculate how the list was at a previous time. WOAH, is there a backend technique thing that I never heard of?

3) Everytime a new batch is getting loaded, the other batches in the buffer and the list are getting invalidated. The recyclerview will call notifyondatasetchanged then and all shown items are getting reloaded (so only the batches that are needed are loaded again). when loading the batches here, we have to make sure, the other batches are not getting invalidated again, since we would have an endless loop of refreshes. on the other hand - what happens when there is a change between reloading the batches here? same again, so unfortunately not the solution.

If i look at the posts at 9gag: you can scroll but you are getting the items of the time you loaded the site (and in the old order). you will only see new posts, if you refresh the page. so is there anything as described in 2)?